# Check first element on a 2D array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Suppose we have a 2d array as follows,

```
[[name1, g, t, w, q, p], [name2, b, g, f, y, o]]
```

I am creating an address book that takes this 2d array and searches the inner arrays based on name1, name2 etc. For that purpose I created the following code,

```
if (catalog.isEmpty()){
       System.out.println("Address book is empty!!!\n");
       continue;
}
System.out.println("Choose the contact name for search");
Scanner retrieve_input = new Scanner(System.in);
String retrieve = retrieve_input.nextLine();
for (ArrayList<String> list : catalog) {
    if (list.get(0).contains(retrieve)) {
       list.indexOf(retrieve);
       System.out.println(catalog);
    } else {
       System.out.println("There's no such name in the book\n");
    }
 }
```

The problem is when I am typing the name1 or 2 on the terminal, I am receiving the else statement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the else because once you find the occurence of `retrieve`, you don't stop and continue looking to the other list.

```
for (ArrayList<String> list : catalog) {
    if (list.get(0).contains(retrieve)) {
       list.indexOf(retrieve);
       System.out.println("FOUND");
       break; // <-------- break if found
    } else {
       System.out.println("There's no such name in the book\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the else statement keeps coming!

Comment: Tried with labeled loop but still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

A lambda seems readable as well,

```
catalog.stream().filter(l -> l.get(0).contains(retrieve)).findFirst().ifPresentOrElse(l -> {
      l.indexOf(retrieve);
      System.out.println("FOUND");
    }, () -> System.out.println("Not found"));
```